# Does this code work universaly, or is it just my system?

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8, locale, wofstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        locale system("");
        locale::global(system);

        wcin.imbue(system);

        wstring data;
        getline(wcin,data);

        wcout.imbue(system);
        wcout << data << L" length=" << data.length() << endl;

        locale utfFile("en_US.UTF-8");
        wofstream file("my_utf_file.txt");
        file.imbue(utfFile);

        file << data;
        file << endl;

        file.close();

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's your system. Locale names are not part of the C++ standard, so `"en_US.UTF-8"` is not universally valid. It's not even certain that a locale similar to it exists.

Answer (score 2):

Won't work in an embedded system without a file system.

Or without that locale installed, of course.