# What is the Windows equivalent for en_US.UTF-8 locale?

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, utf-8, locale

If I want to make the following work on Windows, what is the correct locale and how do I detect that it is actually present: 
[Does this code work universaly, or is it just my system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324385/does-this-code-work-universaly-or-is-it-just-my-system/4324481)

Answer (score 14):

In the past UTF-8 (and some other code pages) wasn't allowed as the system locale because

> Microsoft said that a UTF-8 locale might break some functions as they were written to assume multibyte encodings used no more than 2 bytes per character, thus code pages with more bytes such as UTF-8 (and also GB 18030, cp54936) could not be set as the locale.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_in_Microsoft_Windows#UTF-8

However Microsoft has gradually introduced [UTF-8 locale support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page) and started recommending the ANSI APIs (`-A`) again instead of the Unicode (`-W`) versions like before

> Until recently, Windows has emphasized "Unicode" `-W` variants over `-A` APIs. However, recent releases have used the ANSI code page and `-A` APIs as a means to introduce UTF-8 support to apps. If the ANSI code page is configured for UTF-8, `-A` APIs operate in UTF-8. This model has the benefit of supporting existing code built with `-A` APIs without any code changes.
>
> ### [-A vs. -W APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page#-a-vs--w-apis)

---

Firstly they added a *"Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support"* checkbox since Windows 10 insider build 17035 for setting the locale code page to UTF-8

[image: Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support]

To open that dialog box open start menu, type "region" and select *Region settings > Additional date, time & regional settings > Change date, time, or number formats > Administrative*

After enabling it you can call `setlocal` as normal:

> Starting in Windows 10 build 17134 (April 2018 Update), the Universal C Runtime supports using a UTF-8 code page. This means that `char` strings passed to C runtime functions will expect strings in the UTF-8 encoding. To enable UTF-8 mode, use "UTF-8" as the code page when using `setlocale`. For example, `setlocale(LC_ALL, ".utf8")` will use the current default Windows ANSI code page (ACP) for the locale and UTF-8 for the code page.
>
> [UTF-8 Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setlocale-wsetlocale?view=vs-2019#utf-8-support)

You can also use this in older Windows versions

> To use this feature on an OS prior to Windows 10, such as Windows 7, you must use [app-local deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/universal-crt-deployment?view=vs-2019#local-deployment) or link statically using version 17134 of the Windows SDK or later. For Windows 10 operating systems prior to 17134, only static linking is supported.

---

Later in 2019 they added the ability for programs to use the UTF-8 locale without even setting the UTF-8 beta flag above. You can use the [`/execution-charset:utf-8`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/execution-charset-set-execution-character-set?view=vs-2019) or [`/utf-8`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/utf-8-set-source-and-executable-character-sets-to-utf-8?view=vs-2019) options when compiling with MSVC or set the ActiveCodePage property in appxmanifest

Comment: A nice recap of the new feature! It's amazing it took them so long to say "let's just use utf-8 in the C strings". The `/utf-8` option seems to be unrelated with the checkbox though. It sets the execution and source charsets of the binary but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 12):

Although there isn't good support for named locales, Visual Studio 2010 does include the UTF-8 conversion facets required by C++11: `std::codecvt_utf8` for UCS2 and `std::codecvt_utf8_utf16` for UTF-16:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>
void prepare_file()
{
    // UTF-8 data
    char utf8[] = {'\x7a',                       // latin small letter 'z' U+007a
                   '\xe6','\xb0','\xb4',         // CJK ideograph "water"  U+6c34
                   '\xf0','\x9d','\x84','\x8b'}; // musical sign segno U+1d10b
    std::ofstream fout("text.txt");
    fout.write(utf8, sizeof utf8);
}
void test_file_utf16()
{
    std::wifstream fin("text.txt");
    fin.imbue(std::locale(fin.getloc(), new std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>));
    std::cout << "Read from file using UTF-8/UTF-16 codecvt\n";
    for(wchar_t c; fin >> c; )
        std::cout << std::hex << std::showbase << c << '\n';
}
void test_file_ucs2()
{
    std::wifstream fin("text.txt");
    fin.imbue(std::locale(fin.getloc(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>));
    std::cout << "Read from file using UTF-8/UCS2 codecvt\n";
    for(wchar_t c; fin >> c; )
        std::cout << std::hex << std::showbase << c << '\n';
}
int main()
{
    prepare_file();
    test_file_utf16();
    test_file_ucs2();
}
```

this outputs, on my Visual Studio 2010 EE SP1

```
Read from file using UTF-8/UTF-16 codecvt
0x7a
0x6c34
0xd834
0xdd0b
Read from file using UTF-8/UCS2 codecvt
0x7a
0x6c34
0xd10b
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 1):

Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hzz3tw78.aspx), it would be named "english_us.65001". But code page 65001 is somewhat flaky on Windows.

Comment: Can you please comment more on the "somewhat flaky"?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: I can't summarize it better than http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ablogs.msdn.com+65001

Comment: @MSalters I'm sorry but I just can't find anything both current and detailed enough. What I understand from the short blog posts I read is that Windows doesn't have UTF-8 support at all (which just doesn't make any sense).

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: It doesn't have implicit support. You can't call `MessageBoxA("Hellö")`. However, it has explicit support: `MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS, utf8input.c_str(), ...`

Comment: @MSalters OK, so since my code is explicitly converting into a UTF-8 locale, it should work (damn, I really need to install Windows somewhere so I can test this).

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: What all these answers try to say is that there is no utf-8 locale on windows.

Comment: @Doub there wasn't, but now there is and MS actually recommended to use the UTF-8 locale for portability