# Proper way to fprintf unicode characters

Tags: c++, c, unicode

Here is my simple C/C++ program:

```
int main() {
  FILE* f = fopen("MyTest.log", "w");

  fprintf(f, "%ls\n", L"abc");
  fprintf(f, "%ls\n", L"您好"); // Data from a different locale
  fprintf(f, "%ls\n", L"def");
  fclose(f);

  return 0;
}
```

When I run this program, the generated file does not contain the middle line at all. It appears `fprintf` simply returns back once it detects a different character set in the passed parameter.

I have tested this program on Windows as well as Ubuntu. The same problem at both the places.

Browsing the forum, I found a few hints such as using _setmode() and fwprintf. However, if possible, I would like to stick to fprintf(). Also, my code needs to work on Windows as well as Linux.

Does anyone know to achieve this? Regards.

Comment: Having non-ASCII characters in the source code is not portable and different compilers handle this differently.

Comment: For Windows compilers, your source file **must have BOM**. No such requirement in Linux.

Comment: What encoding should the target file use?

Comment: Fo Linux, the default locale normally has UTF-8 encoding. For your program to work on Linux, you only need to add `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")` in the beginning. Microsoft compilers are not UTF-8 friendly, you will need to jump through hoops with them. If you compile on Windows with GCC, it will work just as well as on Linux.

Comment: In addition to n.m's comment, you don't need that to do with wide character strings. `%s` and `"ÖÜ"` without `L` should do just fine.

Comment: setLocale(LC_ALL, "") works only on Linux. On Windows, it has no effect.

Comment: The example uses hard-coded strings. In reality, the data is coming from some other source.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set locale first to get it work properly..

See this question for more info

[Why doesn't printf format unicode parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007261/why-doesnt-printf-format-unicode-parameters)

you can use UTF-8 char set if your characters are there in this...

[Printing UTF-8 strings with printf - wide vs. multibyte string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528359/printing-utf-8-strings-with-printf-wide-vs-multibyte-string-literals)