# Encoding of "ä", "ö", ... doesn't work properly

Tags: f#-data

I'm using the CsvProvider on a csv File generated out of an Excel. The csv file contains some specific German characters ('ä', 'ö', ...) that are not read correctly.

I tryied with the Encoding parameter, used a stream with UTF8 Encoding, saved the Excel file as ".csv", ".csv" in MS-DOS Format, ... But, the result was always the same.

Here a reduced code sample:

```
open FSharp.Data

type MyCsvProvider = CsvProvider<"Mappe1.csv",Separators=";">

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let csvDatas = MyCsvProvider.Load("..\..\Mappe1.csv")

    for i in csvDatas.Rows do
        printfn "Read: Beispiel='%s' and Änderungsjahr='%d" i.Beispiel i.``�nderungsjahr`` 

    0
```

Here the corresponding CsvFile:

```
Beispiel;Änderungsjahr
Data1;2000
Überlegung;2010
```

And here the result after execution:

```
Read: Beispiel='Data1' and Änderungsjahr='2000
Read: Beispiel='?berlegung' and Änderungsjahr='2010
```

Comment: Correct Title should be "Encoding of "ä", "ö", ... doesn't work properly"

Comment: What encoding does your file use?

Comment: I had a look at excel, but there is no encoding option there... Currently, I use excel to define the file, then I save it as .csv... I'm not doing more than this... I'm using a german localized Windows 10, where I didn't change anything. Did I miss an encoding option somewhere while generating the CSV ?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the problem: Using CSV in Excel generates more or less ASCII, but no UTF. The Format to use is "Unicode (Text)", which generates real unicode, with '\t' as separator instead of ';' or ','. Works for me... Thus I close the question... Thanks to all!

Comment: ASCII is always a bad idea, localized OS or not.

Comment: This was the answer! I had to go into Excel and do a File > Save As > CSV UTF-8

Answer (score -1):

I'm not into F#, but I reckon could be a locale settings for the console. Set a breakpoint and check the actual bytes value with the debugger for the string.

For instance Überlegung starts with Ü which has 0xDC as [ASCII Code](http://www.ascii-code.com) if you get this value from the debugger then it's only the console locale must be set.

Try having a look at this [so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007261/why-doesnt-printf-format-unicode-parameters) about setting the locale even if it is for c++ should be something you can adapt to your environment.

Comment: It's a real F# + FShap.Data topic... The console is able to deliver UTF-8 informations (as the 'Ä' for "Änderungsjahr" shows it in the result of the execution...). I think it's the way the Fsharp.data library parses the .csv file... It doesn't take the right encoding, and I don't know how to correct it...