# Http Digest authentication and utf-8 symbols in request headers

Tags: c++, boost, utf-8, digest-authentication, cpp-netlib

I'm trying to implement [HTTP Digest authentication](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt) in a server based on [cpp-netlib](https://github.com/cpp-netlib/cpp-netlib/) and I'm not sure how to tackle the issue that the `username` attribute in the authorization header could contain unicode symbols - the actual Digest authentication RFC is not specific on this. But practice shows that e.g. Chrome just sends utf-8 encoded username, which would be fine, apart from the fact that cpp-netlib parses the incoming stream and checks if the header contents are alpha numeric using Boost and [std::isalnum](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/isalnum/) and friends (ok, on Linux i could just set the current locale to utf-8, but i'm on Windows) and that of course causes assertions and what not. So, I'm just asking for a general opinion, based on the facts given:

1) Should I just dump this (and I'm really close to that) and just use a customized POST/GET for authentication?
2) Can I anyhow customize the Boost's behaivor (since  the functions that verify alpha numeric values come form boost\algorithm\string\classification) to tackle this? 
3) Maybe such issues are somehow handled in [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) or other web server frameworks that could server as replacements in this situation?

Comment: Doesn't windows support `setlocale()`?

Comment: Well, from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x99tb11d(v=vs.90).aspx - `The set of available languages, country/region codes, and code pages includes all those supported by the Win32 NLS API except code pages that require more than two bytes per character, such as UTF-7 and UTF-8. If you provide a code page like UTF-7 or UTF-8, setlocale will fail, returning NULL.`

Comment: Looks like you are out of luck. See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4324542/315052