# How to printf a unicode string with '%s' specifier?

Tags: c, unicode, printf

I am trying to call `printf()` to output a Unicode character/string using `%s`, but it doesn't print anything.

If I call `printf()` like this:

```
 printf("\xE2\x98\xA0")
```

I get a `☠`.

But, if I use `%ls` like this:

```
printf("%ls", "☠")  /* or */
printf("%ls", L"☠") /* or */
printf("%ls", L"\xE2\x98\xA0")
```

I get nothing printed;

Also, how can I declare a `wchar_t` string with Unicode characters inside of it?  `wchar_t wstro[50] = L"☠"` doesn't work.

Do I need to `malloc()` a `wchar_t` then put Unicode data in it?

Comment: Code examples use lower case `s`.  Suggest editing your text/title to reflect `s` rather than `S` - if that is really what you are doing.  Case matters in C.

Comment: Ref: [Unicode Character 'SKULL AND CROSSBONES'](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2620/index.htm)

Comment: What does `printf("<%s>\n", u8"\xE2\x98\xA0");` (this needs C11 compiler) or `printf("<%s>\n", "\xE2\x98\xA0");` printf for you?

Comment: You need to add a `\n` at the end of printf

Comment: If `printf("\xE2\x98\xA0")` works but `printf("%ls", L"☠")` doesn't, `printf` is not encoding the Unicode string as UTF-8, and the console isn't handling whatever `printf` is actually encoding to. `E2 98 A0` is the UTF-8 encoded form of `☠`, but `"\xE2\x98\xA0"` is not the same as `L"\xE2\x98\xA0"`. You can always encode Unicode strings to UTF-8 manually, such as with platform APIs or 3rd party libraries (although UTF-8 is not hard to implement from scratch, either). Also, `wchar_t wstro[50] = L"☠"` works fine, so if it is not working for you, you likely have a buggy compiler.

Comment: `wchar_t` and `L` prefix is for Windows, but it sounds like you are on Mac or Linux

Comment: For what it's worth, `printf("%ls", "☠")` works for me, on Ubuntu with gcc. The others don't print anything at all.

Comment: What OS are you using?  What encoding is the source file saved as?  These details matter when dealing with console I/O.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani `wchar_t` and the `L` prefix are NOT limited to just Windows. They are part of the language standard and are implemented on every platform. Just not the same way on every platform.

Comment: @ArndtJonasson Are you sure you succeeded with `printf("%ls", "☠")`? The format `%ls` is for `wchar_t*`, maybe you tried `printf("%s", "☠")`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I can't succeed with `wchar_t` on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/7eLCGb) - it's expecting UTF8. The compiler is expected to understand `wchar_t*` strings, but non-Windows system may not know what to do with it.

Comment: Yeah still the same problem, when i printf("%ls\n", wstro) with wstro[2] = "0xC9", i have an error message on stdout "printf: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character"
And i am on windows 10, using Clion. At school i am on Mac, it;s the same result.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani No, you are right. I meant to write that  `printf("%s", "☠")` works for me.

Comment: Warning: Microsoft does not follow the ISO C standard for `%s` and `%ls` in format strings.  It would be useful to say whether you are using a Microsoft implementation or not

Answer (score 5):

You are confusing Unicode, with UTF-8, and both with `wchar_t`.

Unicode is something abstract, with code point, combining characters and other properties.

UTF-8 is a common way to encode Unicode, and that it is compatible with ASCII (in case of ASCII only strings), and compatible with C strings (so zero terminated (and no other 0 bytes in the string). `\xE2\x98\xA0` is UTF-8 representation.

The character `☠` is probably also encoded in UTF-8. This depends on your editor, but often editors do not use wchar_t.

So: with UTF-8 you should just use `%s` and not `%ls`. So your 3 attempts are wrong.

I general, use UTF-8 and so `char*` and normal strings functions (just do no break strings at random byte, but this mean also not to break strings after random UTF-8 code points if it is followed by some combining code points.

You may use wchar_t, but usually with protocols that use wchar_t, but especially on this case, you should make extra care, because the size of wchar_t could not be compatible with the desired character size (of expected encoding) [e.g. your system and so wchar_t could be just 2 bytes, but so you can use UCS2, but not UTF-32, or the contrary if the system defines wchar_t as 4 bytes).

So keep things simple and try to use just UTF-8, and use it as normal C strings.

Comment: Ok now i understand much more what the differences between the 3.
I succeeded to print a multibyte character with %ls, but what i don't understand now is why %s can also print a multibyte character.
For example,
wchar_t x[] = L"a\xEF\xB7\xB0z"; printf("%ls\n", x); print the same as printf("%s\n", "a\xEF\xB7\xB0z");

Comment: But the character printed is encoded on 3bytes : ﷰ = 11101111 10110111 10110000, so why %s can print it ?

Comment: Because C see them as normal string. You should not use string length to count of characters, but many properties are similar. A C string is an array of chars (equivalent to bytes on current epoch), terminated with `\0`. UTF-8 is constructed (so by design) to be compatible with C-strings. So `\0` is found only at end of a UTF-8 string. UTF-16 the termination is `\0\0` and `\0` is found e.g. in every ASCII and latin1 characters. So they are not compatible, so there is `wchar_t`. Note already with ASCII (in control character), there were sequences of characters as single entity.

Comment: *often editors do not use wchar_t* It doesn't have anything to do with the editor. If it's a new editor/compiler on a Unix based system, it most likely understands `wchar_t buf[] = L"☠"`, but it doesn't support printing it.

Comment: in those codes you are outputting 3 bytes and your terminal or display environment is interpreting it as UTF-8.

Comment: I am sorry, but i still don't understand how i can use the %ls of printf.
wchar_t *wstr = L"é";  printf("%ls\n", wstr); doesn't work. The error message on stderror is "printf: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character". I tried to change file encoding of Clion from UTB8 to UTB16 but it's worse.

Comment: Do not use the `l` flag in `%s`. UTF-8 are strings of chars not string of wchar_t.

Answer (score 5):

*This answer assumes you are working in MS Windows*

---

It's pretty sad that we're in 2018 and this stuff all still doesn't work properly . But here is the state of things:

`printf("\xE2\x98\xA0");` (which is the same as `printf("%s", "\xE2\x98\xA0");`) works because you are just outputting 3 characters to the output stream. There is no Unicode or special character processing occuring in the C language. It is your terminal environment which looks for UTF-8 strings in the output and chooses display glyphs accordingly.

Similarly, if you wrote the output to a file (using `fprintf`, or stream redirection) you would see the file contains `0xE2, 0x98, 0xA0` and then you may choose to use a text file viewer that converts UTF-8 to display glyphs.

This part is all fine, and you can (and probably should) write your program to only ever write UTF-8 encoded characters to `FILE` streams.

---

The problem starts when we want to output `wchar_t` characters. In theory this should work:

```
printf("%ls", L"\u2620");
```

What is supposed to happen is that `wcstombs` is called to convert the unicode code point sequence into a multi-byte sequence.  But which multi-byte format to use? UTF-8 has become ubiquitous now, but in the past there were also other formats like ShiftJIS, Big-5 etc.

You have to specify the multibyte format by using `setlocale`. And the details of locales are implementation-defined.

Here's the kicker. **There is no C locale supported by Windows for general UTF-8 output**.  If you try `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, ".65001");` it just doesn't work.

You can output certain subsets of Unicode by using a supported locale. For example [the MSDN example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/mbstowcs-mbstowcs-l) using `Japanese_Japan.932` works, outputting the Unicode input as Shift-JIS. (Not UTF-8).

What's worse is that if you use the Windows API function `WideStringToMultiByte`, it **does** accept the "locale" of `CP_UTF8`.  You can use this function to convert `L"\u2620";` to a `char` buffer and `printf` that, producing UTF-8 output.

But of course you cannot "plug this in" to the `FILE` stream processing, which only calls `wcstombs` and not `WideStringToMultiByte`.

Why didn't they allow `".UTF-8"` as a locale for `wcstombs`? Malicious behaviour? Who knows.

---

The next thing that *should work* in theory is:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("a.txt", "w");
fwide(fp, 1);
fwprintf(fp, L"\u2620");
```

However in actuality, the MS runtime doesn't actually do anything with `fwide`; it doesn't support wide-oriented streams.  The Microsoft implementations of `wprintf` family actually just output narrow characters, not wide characters, and they use the same `wcstombs` method that the narrow printf family did.

So, that code doesn't work, and the code from the Japanese wcstombs example, `fwprintf(fp, L"\u3603");` (with the .932 CP set) outputs the multibyte sequence instead of the raw wide character.

To write a UTF-16 file via the `stdio.h` API you actually have no choice but to use narrow characters and treat it like a binary file.

Comment: You can use `wprintf(L"%s", L"☠")`, but only in Visual Studio, where you call [_setmode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492077) first. In other compilers you have to use `WriteConsoleW`. Characters like `'☠'` are not supported with default console font, so you have to change the font too. That's doable in Visual Studio but it needs even more fiddling in other compilers. `fwprintf` will work if you open the file in binary mode (BOM would be very useful). Though I prefer to save the file in UTF8. With Linux `printf("%s", "☠")` or `printf("%s", u8"☠")` will do, probably same with Mac.

Comment: [There's a UTF-8 locale in Windows since 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63454192/995714)

Answer (score 0):

### Code that works for Windows

(I use it)

Environment: W7/64 w/ ConEmu console, W10 Terminal or ConEmu, CP **always** set to **65001**.

Compiler : gcc version 11.2.0 (MinGW-W64 x86_64-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders)

**DOES NOT WORK in W7 default Windows console** even w/ CP65001.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>                     /* malloc */
#include <string.h>                     /* strlen... */
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>
//
main( int argc , char *argv[])
{
  // .... code here
  printf("%s", "\u25BA");  /* right triangle */
  // ....
}
```

Result:

```
C:\Users\gm\C>gets John MARTHA william
►martha
C:\Users\gm\C>
```

As previously stated by others, locale does not seem to provide any help in making this work on any consoles I tried.

Other syntaxes (`L"\u25BA"`, `printf("%ls",...)`, ...) did NOT bring me the expected result with this gcc compiler under W7 nor W10 on any consoles I tried.