# What exactly is the expected format of the locale in setlocale()?

Tags: c++, setlocale

If I use the `fputws` without `setlocale`, only ASCII letters get printed. It seems that `setlocale` is necessary, and according to [this site](https://c-for-dummies.com/blog/?p=2578), both `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "UTF-8")` and `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_us.UTF-8")` would work.

But when I tried it, `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "UTF-8")` did not work, and it printed "Hello ". Only with `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_us.UTF-8")`, I get "Hello ねこ 2". I read the comment on that page, and he also said "UTF-8" did not work (he used GCC, I used VC++). I read some manual pages, but they did not specifically say what the format should be. On [CPP reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/locale/setlocale), the example is using only formats like "en_US.UTF-8", but on [tutorials point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_setlocale.htm), the example uses formats like "en_GB".

Is `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "UTF-8")` a correct call?

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "UTF-8");
//setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_us.UTF-8");
FILE* output = _wfopen(L"output.txt", L"w");
fputws(L"Hello ねこ 2", output);
fclose(output);
```

Comment: Damn Vegetables, What was the return value of `setlocale()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is system specific. To quote the cppreference page you linked to:

> system-specific locale identifier. Can be "" for the user-preferred locale or "C" for the minimal locale

I *think* "UTF-8" is an invalid locale name generally (it needs the language identifier at minimum, not 100% on that though). However generally you will want to simply use "" in order to default to the user preference (which, I would hope, is correct for displaying their input).

Comment: This lack of consistency is kind of annoying.`setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "enUS-UTF-8")` worked on Windows 10, but when I ran the same code on Windows Server 2019, it did not work (Japanese was not printed). I changed LC_CTYPE to LC_ALL, then it worked. I guess trial and error is the only way...

Comment: @DamnVegetables In older Windows you have to use UTF-16 because UTF-8 isn't allowed as a locale. But you can link with the new stdlib from MS to use UTF-8 as a locale in older Windows. [What is the Windows equivalent for en_US.UTF-8 locale?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63454192/995714)