# What is TCHAR and how does it differ from WCHAR?

Tags: c, windows, types, wchar, tchar

This question should've had an answer nowadays here, but there is nothing explaining what exactly `TCHAR` is on stackoverflow (all I found is an explanation of the difference between `TCHAR` and `_TCHAR`).

All I know is that `TCHAR` and `_TCHAR` are considered to be the same and on some platforms `TCHAR` may be the same as `WCHAR`. But all that is just a presumption.

What is `TCHAR` and how does it differ from `WCHAR`?

Comment: C is case-sensitive.

Comment: @ikegami ok I'll edit that

Comment: btw why is it even in uppercase if there is no `tchar`?

Comment: @Kaiyaha because the tags can only be in lowercase

Comment: last windows without unicode suppot was millenium. since then all this is a waste stuff

Comment: @Jabberwocky so is that to differentiate a type from a tag?

Comment: @Kaiyaha I meant the [tags in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). Where did you se `tchar` in lowercase?

Comment: @Kaiyaha It is all fairly well explained in the reference documentation under [Working with Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/working-with-strings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TCHAR` is either `char` or `wchar_t` depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined or not.

Using `TCHAR` and `TCHAR`-based types allow a library to work with programs that define `UNICODE` and programs that don't alike.

Comment: So if I declare `tchar`, I provide more portability for my code, do I?

Comment: Yes, if you use `TCHAR` and `TCHAR`-based types, it's more portable. I've added something to that effect to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The *TCHAR* can be either a char or *WCHAR* based on the platform, and the *WCHAR* will always be a 16-bit Unicode character, *wchar_t*.

Comment: Will I have portable code if I specify `tchar` instead of `char`?

Comment: @Kaiyaha no. Just avoid all those TCHAR and wchar_t and use UTF-8 everywhere. It's possible in Windows right now: [What is the Windows equivalent for en_US.UTF-8 locale?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63454192/995714)