# Displaying "?" instead of unicode character in C++ Windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

I created C++ project with Visual Studio 2019, which prints russian and armenian characters. But in command line prints **?**

**Source.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    cout << "\u053e абв";
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
? ???
```

In editor too

[image]

When I used UTF-8 it outputs this

```
╨░╨▒╨▓
```

When I add codepage 20861 displaying **? 6** times

Comment: Even though you set your program's locale, your C++ compiler is still generating (likely) UTF-8 sequences. Your terminal console is also likely using a different codepage (likely UTF-8) too. Your editor is simply confused. i18n is hard.

Comment: Using std::wcout << L"\u053e абв\n"; makes the editor show the string correctly. Though the output is still not as desired. It works perfectly on Linux ').

Comment: Try to add ```SetConsoleOutputCP(1251); SetConsoleCP(1251);``` at the beggining

Comment: It gives 11 errors

Comment: the source code must be the same code page as in the code page you're setting. But stop doing that and just [use UTF-8 instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63454192/995714)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you could try to use [the Code Page Identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

As the following code:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "20866");
```

[image]