# How to write a portable c++ code with unicode support?

Tags: c++, unicode, c++14, unicode-literals

I have the below program, which tries to print Unicode characters on a console by enabling the `_O_U16TEXT` mode for the console:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>

int main()
{
   _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
   wprintf(L"test\n \x263a\x263b Hello from C/C++\n");
   
   return 0;
}
```

What is unclear to me is that, I have seen many C++ projects (with the same code running on Windows and Linux) and using a macro called `_UNICODE`. I have the following questions:

1. Under what circumstance do I need to define the `_UNICODE` macro?
2. Does enabling the `_UNICODE` macro mean I need to separate the ASCII related code by using `#ifdef _UNICODE`? In case of the above program, do I need to put any `#ifdef UNICODE` and the ASCII code processing in `#else`?
3. What extra do I need to enable the code to have Unicode support in  C/C++? Do I need to link to any specific libraries on Windows and Linux?
4. Why does my sample program above not need to define the `_UNICODE` macro?
5. When I define the `_UNICODE` macro, how does the code know whether it uses UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32? How do I decide between these Unicode types?

Comment: It is used by the SDK headers, you don't need `#include <windows.h>` in a console app.  wprintf() unambiguously uses wchar_t, when you target Windows then it is utf16.

Comment: @hanspassant - Could you please elaborate your answer in view of my bulleted points in the question as that would really clarify my basics where I seem not to connect the dots.

Comment: `_UNICODE` macro determines whether e.g. `CreateFile` macro expands to `CreateFileA` (a function taking `char*` arguments) or `CreateFileW` (a function taking `wchar_t*` arguments). Or whether `_T("x")` expands to `"x"` or  `L"x"`. It has no effect on "portable C++ code", if by that you mean code that limits itself to C++ core language and standard library, and doesn't use any Windows-specific features. Historically, the macro allowed writing code that could be compiled both for Windows 95 (MBCS-based) and Windows NT (Unicode-based).

Comment: Since you are using `wprintf` in your example - a Windows-specific header `tchar.h` provides a macro [`_tprintf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/printf-printf-l-wprintf-wprintf-l?view=msvc-170#generic-text-routine-mappings) that expands to `printf` or `wprintf` based on whether `_UNICODE` is defined.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - What has UNICODE meaning on Linux systems ? As per your statement expansion of CreateFile to CreateFileA or CreateFileW is meaningful only for Windows, isn't it?

Comment: I'm reasonably sure `_UNICODE` is Windows-specific and has no special meaning to a typical C++ toolchain used on Linux. I'm not really familiar with non-Windows toolchains, though. What I'm 100% sure about is that `_UNICODE` macro is not mentioned in the C++ standard, and has no effect on "portable C++ code" (defined, again, as code confined within the four corners of the standard).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - Since you mentioned that you are not familiar , So will you be able to clarify that how do we deal with the unicode on Unix systems i.e how will relevant c++ code will look in Unix system?

Comment: No, I don't know enough about Unix-based systems, sorry. I'm reasonably sure that defining `UNICODE` or `_UNICODE` would neither help nor hurt. Note also that `_setmode` and `_fileno` (used in your example) are Windows-specific.

Comment: If you really want portable code, forget about `wstring`. Use UTF-8 encoded strings and convert them to UTF-16 when passing to WinAPI functions with W postfix. AFAIK most modern unix systems use UTF-8 by default.

Comment: @Genjutsu - is wstring windows specific? if not, then why do you say to ignore those? How will i implement unicode support in linux? Can you elaborate as your response isn't very concise in explaining what you want to say?

Comment: `wstring` is utf16 on windows, but UTF32 on linux. First, you should define what is unicode support for your application. On Linux you don't really need to do anything, simple `cout << "Hello мир!";` will most likely work out of the box. On windows you may need to call `SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);` first.

Comment: just avoid `std::wstring` and use UTF-8 everywhere with [UTF-8 locale in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63454192/995714)

Comment: `UNICODE` (no underscore) applies to the Win32 API only.  `_UNICODE` (with underscore) applies to the C runtime library. They are commonly (un)defined together, but they are technically separate.

Comment: Use a third-party library which has already took care of portability for I/O and string handling.