# C++ Microsoft docs - File handling / Get folder path

Tags: c++

I have learned C/C++ Basics and practiced , but I have hard time understanding
Microsoft documentation and find it confusing [Documention example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifiledialog-getfolder)

for example : I try to create command line program that should let the user open
folder dialog and choose folder , as result the folders path should be stored in variable
did research and found that there is many ways to achieve this goal but the best way is using IFileDialog::GetFolder method (shobjidl_core.h)
what the difference between file dialogs?

The main question :
How to get folders path as string variable based on user choice from file dialog?

There is c++ resources with practical tutorials ?

I try to understand how I use the following dialog :
[Folder dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shbrowseforfoldera)

it refernces me to:
[BROWSEINFOA structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/ns-shlobj_core-browseinfoa)

Would be very helpful if someone could explain how I can use this folder dialog or something better

any great tutorial of windows/linux file system handling

Comment: Have a read of [Get Started with Win32 and C++ - Working with Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/working-with-strings)

Comment: As I understand TCHAR is legacy , how can I focus on must recent C++ libraries instead of legacy ones

Comment: you can just use the [`en_US.UTF-8` locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63454192/995714) and use `char*` everywhere for simplicity and portability. All modern platforms will just work with UTF-8

Comment: I tried using std::locale::global(std::locale("en_US.UTF-8")); but got same error
also it makes mess with chars I used in other parts in my code , I edited my question to more modern libraries as I understand

Comment: @None you need some more compiler flags to make `std::locale("en_US.UTF-8")` work

Comment: I have solved the issue using , wcout but I still don't understand the differences between file dialog why they kept in different libraries , for example : SHBrowseForFolder , IFileOpenDialog , CFileDialog ....

Comment: @phuclv: you can't  force the `*A` Windows functions to accept or return UTF-8. The only Unicode functions are the `*W` variants. You get a proper mess if you pass a non-English UTF-8 string to an Windows ANSI function. The compiler is entirely not involved in this, nor is `std::locale`.

Comment: @MSalters did you see the link above? MS nowadays recommends to use UTF-8 locale and the `*A` Win32 APIs nowadays can accept a UTF-8 string. Both the compiler and Windows SDK involve in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to wcout to print out path

```
    TCHAR path[260];
    BROWSEINFO bi = { 0 };
    LPITEMIDLIST pidl = SHBrowseForFolder(&bi);
    SHGetPathFromIDList(pidl, path);
    wcout << path << '\n';
```

We can use com interface as well :

```
int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow);
    {
        HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            IFileOpenDialog* pFileOpen;

            // Create the FileOpenDialog object.
            hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOpenDialog, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL,IID_IFileOpenDialog, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pFileOpen));
            // if object created ( that's com object )
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                // Show the Open dialog box.
                hr = pFileOpen->Show(NULL);

                // Get the file name from the dialog box.
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    IShellItem* pItem;
                    hr = pFileOpen->GetResult(&pItem);
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    {
                        PWSTR pszFilePath;
                        hr = pItem->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, &pszFilePath);

                        // Display the file name to the user.
                        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                        {
                            MessageBoxW(NULL, pszFilePath, L"File Path", MB_OK);
                            CoTaskMemFree(pszFilePath);
                            cout << pszFilePath;

                            std::string stringtoconvert;

                            std::wstring temp = std::wstring(stringtoconvert.begin(), stringtoconvert.end());
                            LPCWSTR lpcwstr = temp.c_str();
                        }
                        pItem->Release();
                    }
                }
                pFileOpen->Release();
            }
            CoUninitialize();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Important to mention :
Open and Save As common dialog boxes ( [commdlg.h](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/) ) have been superseded by the [Common Item Dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/common-file-dialog)

For linux and other platforms there is cross platforms libraries like Qt and more , here is a link for [UI solutions](https://philippegroarke.com/posts/2018/c++_ui_solutions/)

and about Microsoft documentation : I think there should be simpler examples and explanations its complicated & frustrating to learn this way.