# Is there a way I can configure VS Code or Code::Blocks so that the terminal can output Russian characters?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, codeblocks

[I have tried to change the encoding in vs code, but the Russian characters keep showing as "???" in the terminal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Km6Vg.png)

Comment: Should just work, unless you're on Windows.  If you are on Windows, [Unicode support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63454192/4641116) for the C runtime.

Comment: Encoding settings apply to files not to terminal.

Comment: Yes I'm on windows

Comment: This might be a code page issue since you're on Windows. Try running `chcp 65001` to change the console's codepage to utf8. If you want to change the default, see https://superuser.com/q/269818/1749748. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try add `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian")` to begin of your code.

Comment: I have tried to do that but I get the same result

Answer (score 0):

```
auto utf16_to_utf8 = [](const std::wstring &value) -> std::string {
    int len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, value.c_str(), -1, NULL, 0, 0, 0);
    if (len)
    {
        std::string utf8 = std::string(len, '\0');
        WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, value.c_str(), -1, &utf8[0], len, 0, 0);
        return utf8;
    }
    return std::string();
};

auto utf8_to_utf16 = [](const std::string &value) -> std::wstring {
    int len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, value.c_str(), -1, NULL, 0, 0, 0);
    if (len)
    {
        std::wstring utf16 = std::wstring(len, '\0');
        MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, value.c_str(), -1, &utf16[0], len, 0, 0);
        return utf16;
    }
    return std::string();
};
```

Then do: `std::wcout<<utf8_to_utf16(u8"Привет\n");`
Windows terminals have been notoriously bad with displaying UTF-8, until recently in Windows 10 or 11. So you'd be better off outputting UTF-16.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to tick "Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support" in the System Region Settings.