# C: Run a System Command with non-ASCII character?

Tags: c, windows, cmd, clang, system

You can easly execute a system command with C [with this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43116/how-can-i-run-an-external-program-from-c-and-parse-its-output).

But, how can I input a command with non-ASCII character? If I run this program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>    
int main() {
    system("echo \"Coração, fé, café!\" ");
}
```

I get:

```
"CoraÃ§Ã£o, fÃ©, cafÃ©!"
```

I don't want to convert the terminal to a correct charset (or encodding). I want to input the non-ASCII characters.

Let's say I have the file:

```
C:\Cafe Coracao.txt     <-- No ascents
C:\Café Coração.txt
```

So this program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>    
int main() {
    system("type \"C:\\Cafe Coracao.txt\"");    <--  Will work
    system("type \"C:\\Café Coração.txt\"");    <--  Will fail
}
```

How to make this work?

Comment: [Unicode Escape Seq](https://dencode.com/en/string/unicode-escape), there is also a text converter. [This](https://godbolt.org) works on my Macintosh, could be diff fro your machine. I used `printf()` instead of `system` but should still work.

Comment: On Windows you would likely need to use the [_wsystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/system-wsystem?view=msvc-170) function with a wide character string.

Comment: Given the output, the source file is encoded in UTF-8.  With the Microsoft compiler, using the `/utf-8` compiler switch to set the source encoding to UTF-8 works with your code.  I don't have `clang` installed, but try compiling with `-finput-charset=utf8`.  Note to @RetiredNinja it works with both `system` and `_wsystem` if the source encoding is interpreted correctly, at least on the MS compiler.

Comment: @RetiredNinja that's not true. You can use UTF-8 on the console. And nowadays [UTF-8 locale is also supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63454192/995714)

Comment: What is the encoding of the c source file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdlib.h>    
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    {
        FILE* f = fopen("C:\\Temp\\Café Coração.txt", "w");
        if (f)
        {
            fputs("Here's some text\n", f);
            fclose(f);
            system("type \"C:\\Temp\\Café Coração.txt\"");
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not create utf-8 file!\n");
        }
    }

    {
        FILE* f = _wfopen(L"C:\\Temp\\Café CoraçãoW.txt", L"w");
        if (f)
        {
            fputs("Here's some text\n", f);
            fclose(f);
            _wsystem(L"type \"C:\\Temp\\Café CoraçãoW.txt\"");
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not create utf-16 file!\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Notepad++ identifies the source file as UTF-8 BOM. Running it on Windows 10 Pro 22H2 19045.3086

Compiled with Visual Studio 2022 using the Microsoft compiler with no special flags both files are created with the correct names and `type` works on both of them.

Compiled with clang 15.0.1 installed with Visual Studio using the command line `clang -finput-charset=utf-8 test.c -o tt.exe` the first file is created and incorrectly named `CafÃ© CoraÃ§Ã£o.txt`, the second is correctly named `Café CoraçãoW.txt`. Both of the `type` commands work, which I'd expect since it's the same string literal for the name, but if the file already exists with the correct name then `type` fails since the names don't match. The results are the same without the `-finput-charset=utf-8` flag. I also tried the `-fexec-charset=utf-8` flag with no change to the behavior.

I'd say you're best off using wide strings for filenames/paths if you're compiling with `clang` unless there are other options to make it work that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

For one hand, in this question, I tried to compile the code. But what I was really trying was to get the string from console and then work with it.

This is a really old DOS problem. Anyway, if you run this code:

```
int main() {
    FILE *f, *file;
    file = fopen("resultado.txt","w");
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<256; i++) {
        char result[60];
        snprintf(result, 12, "echo %c %i", (char)i, i);
        f = popen(result, "r");
        char linha[512];
        while (fgets(linha, 512, f)) {
            fprintf(file, "%c %i --> C  ", (char)i,  (int)i);
            fprintf(file, "%s", linha);
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

It will print in the text all ASCII code and how the console see it. From 0 to 127 it is equal. After it, you need to change. This is `Code Page 850` and I don't see an easy way to do it, but I did it myself.

Getting all printable character, I have this array:

```
const unsigned int translate[] = {199,252,233,226,228,224,229,231,234,235,232,239,238,236,196,197,201,230,198,244,246,242,251,249,255,214,220,248,163,216,215,131,225,237,243,250,241,209,170,186,191,174,172,189,188,161,171,187,0,0,0,0,0,193,194,192,169,0,0,0,0,162,165,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,227,195,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,164,240,208,202,203,200,0,205,206,207,0,0,0,0,166,204,0,211,223,212,210,245,213,181,254,222,218,219,217,253,221,175,180,173,177,0,190,182,167,247,184,176,168,183,185,179,178,0};
```

Now loop all string you get and use

```
for (int i= 0; i< size; i++) {
   unsigned char mychar = (unsigned char)text[i];
   if (mychar>= 128){
         mychar =translate[mychar - 128];      
   }
   text[i] = mychar
}
```

And now you can work with the string in normal ASCII in C program.