# c++ string UTF-8 encoding

Tags: c++, windows, string, utf-8

I'm new in c++, and I tried to write a very simple code, but the result is wrong, and I don't know how to fix it.

The code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string test_string = "aáeéöôőüűč♥♦♣♠";
    cout << test_string << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But the result is: `a├íe├ę├Â├┤┼Ĺ├╝┼▒─ŹÔÖąÔÖŽÔÖúÔÖá`

I am on Windows, using Code::Blocks.

Comment: The result isn't as much "wrong" as it is "unexpected". You need to broaden your expectations and understanding of your environment.

Comment: Works for me. What operating system are you using? Compiler? Source file encoding?

Comment: good luck trying to display utf-8 in a windows console, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379240/is-there-a-windows-command-shell-that-will-display-unicode-characters you will have to change the codepage prior to running your program.

Comment: What I always do -- which might or might not be the answer you are looking for -- is to encode the string as UTF-8 in a tool and put it in as escape codes, byte for byte, like `test_string = "a\xc3\xa1""e\xc3\xa9\xc3\xb6\xc3\xb4\xc5\x91\xc3\xbc\xc5\xb1\xc4\x8d\xe2\x99\xa5\xe2\x99\xa6\xe2\x99\xa3\xe2\x99\xa0"`. This way I am sure that the string is correct UTF-8 no matter the encoding of the source code file or any locale settings.

Comment: Are you limited to standard C++, or are you willing to use Windows APIs?

Answer (score 1):

Save file as UTF-8 without BOM signature, and try use printf().

```
//Save As UTF8 without BOM signature
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);
    char test_string[] = "aáeéöôőüűč♥♦♣♠";
    printf(test_string);
    return 0;
}
```

And the result is: `aáeéöôőüűč♥♦♣♠`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately working with UTF-8 on Windows is very problematic.

On Linux, you can simply `wstring` like this:

[Does this code work universaly, or is it just my system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324385/does-this-code-work-universaly-or-is-it-just-my-system/4324481)

But unfortunately Windows doesn't have an UTF-8 locale, so you are left with Windows API.

http://www.siao2.com/2007/01/03/1392379.aspx